# Send variables via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from my javascript code over to the server side PHP code. I know this must be done via an ajax call which i believe i have done correctly, however accessing the variable i pass from my ajax into my php is when i run into trouble as i am new to php. Here is my code i have thus far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
    var id = $(a).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'cao.php',
    data: { "id" : id },
    success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert("success!");
                        }


    });
    });
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="cao.php" id="Barselona" >Barselona</a>
    </br>
    <a href="cao.php" id="Beograd" >Beograd</a>


    </body>
    </html>



    //  cao.php
       <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $uid = $_POST['id'];
    echo "www" . $uid;

    }

?>
```

I'm trying to pass my javascript variable "ID" to php ($uID), however i've gone wrong somewhere along the road. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected result? What is the result? What gave you done to debug it?

Comment: What the error it returns? does ajax post to the PHP page correctly !

Comment: when i click on <a> it shows blank php page, instead browser show echo.

Answer (score 0):

Should correct your problem :

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $.post($(this).attr('href'), {id: $(this).attr('id')}, function(data) {
       alert('Success (or not ?!)');
   });
});
```

Comment: I added this and now when i click on link it doesnt redirect to cao.php

Comment: See my edits, cause `var id = $(a).attr('id');` can't work in your code.

Comment: i c/p your edit and  it still doesnt redirect to cao.php

Comment: when i remove e.preventDefault(); it redirects me but page is blank